# Shopify Gatsby checkout

Tags: shopify, gatsby

If you've ever watched Trevor Harmon's talk on [Gatsby and Shopify](https://youtu.be/tUtuGAFOjYI), he does explain the integration between both.

Basically, in Shopify, all you need is

1. Shopify partner account (for someone aiming to test this)
2. Bogus gateway for payments
3. Create new private app in Shopify. Storefront API, and select the boxes to read product tags and read customer tags.
4. Create products. Options - size, color, ... Variance - combination of options.

Now, to pull data to Gatsby one needs the plugin [gatsby-source-shopify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-shopify/) and allShopifyProduct has variants with shopifyID and that's what one wants to use.

Then, for the checkout, he mentions **shopify-buy** plugin. Thing is, I couldn't find such plugin.

Found one with similar name called [gatsby-plugin-shopify-buy](https://github.com/ginlane/gatsby-plugin-shopify-buy) but it has
a slightly different name (In Gatsby plugins already noticed there's people giving similar names to some good ones as a way to get people to use them) and different methods, so that's not the one.

How should I implement the checkout then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [js-buy-sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk) plugin is the one you were looking for. For the checkout you'd need something like this

```
// Create an empty checkout
client.checkout.create().then((checkout) => {
  // Do something with the checkout
  console.log(checkout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for [`gatsby-plugin-shopify-buy`](https://github.com/ginlane/gatsby-plugin-shopify-buy)?

According to the documentation, the `context` passed to the `StoreContext.Consumer` or as the `prop` `storeContext` to `withStoreContext` child components.

Comment: That one I could find too. In Gatsby plugins already noticed there's people giving similar names to some good ones as a way to get people to use them. Judging from the amount of people using that one, I'd say that's the case too.

Comment: The name during the presentation min 17:35 it is being defined as "shopify-buy" (and anytime the presenter references it).

Comment: In min 17:37 shows the methods in the other which are different too.